# I am trying to use Restart on Failure option(under install service) with various options

Tags: service, install4j, recovery

I am trying to use Restart on Failure option(under install service) with various options. Please let me know how to do for following scenario.

`property="restartOnFailure"`

`First failure=restart`
`Second failure=restart`
`subsequently failure=take no action`
`restart service after 2 mins`

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is not configurable in install4j.